# How to write HDFS bolt for Twitter Streaming using Storm

Tags: apache-storm, hadoop2, bigdata

How to write data from storm stream to hdfs
I am referring to add in code TweetTopology.java
lesson2 - stage5 - (Twitterfeed needs to store in hdfs )

Can you help to write hdfs bolt here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at HdfsBolt, already implemented :
https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hdfs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt/HdfsBolt.java

All you have to do is set it up with the appropriate/desired configuration and it writes your data to hdfs.